# why logical and with change of order give different output?

Tags: c++, c++11, logical-operators

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    cout<<-1&&0; //output is -1

    cout<<0&&-1; //output is 0
    return 10;        
}
```

i completly understand second output but unable to understand first output.As in second output and first operand is 0 then it dont evaluate 2nd operator and give 0 but in first it evaluate-1(which is true as it is non zero) then it has to evaluate 0 and give 0 as result not -1.

Comment: On g++ v7.3.0, your code does not compile or link. So it does not  run, so it outputs nothing at all.  In 2 places:  "error: invalid operands of types ‘int’ and ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to binary ‘operator<<’ "

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are a victim of misunderstanding [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).  The operator `<<` has a higher precedence than `&&`, and so it will be completely evaluated before the `&&` is.

Your statements are equivalent to:

```
   (cout << -1) && 0;
   (cout << 0) && -1;
```

If you want the `&&` to evaluate first, you need to do this:

```
   cout << (-1 && 0);
   cout << (0 && -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an order of operations issue.  If you add parenthesis around the logical operations, then the code makes sense:

```c++
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

    cout << (-1 && 0) << endl; //output is -1

    cout << (0 && -1) << endl; //output is 0
    return 10;

}
```

output:

```
0
0
```

In the original code, the << and -1 are evaluated before the -1 && 0.

Hence, the -1 is printed from the first line and the 0 is printed from the second line.